# Intune device not in Endpoint Manager

Tags: azure, microsoft, microsoft-intune, mdm, endpoint

One of our devices is visible in MS Azure AD > Devices with Jointype = Azure AD joined and MDM = Microsoft Intune, but not visible in MS Endpoint Manager.

Any experiences/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you connect the device into MS Intune ?
the proper way to add devices into Intune is using "Company Portal" in microsoft store. After you install it, Sign-in with your work AD account, follow the steps, Enroll and activate

Comment: I think I know what the issue is: device (laptop) was enrolled into Intune, but user is not signed in with is MS account, but with a local account. Our engineer made an error while configuring the laptop. Normally we don't allow local accounts. But ok, when this happens, it wont show up in your Endpoint Manager.